# card class constructor and formatting toString() problems for bridge game

Tags: java

Some info about the instance variables.

1. int rank – holds  a number between 2 and 14 (inclusive) which indicates the rank of the card
2. char suit – holds a character representing the suit of the card ('C','D','H','S')  to represent one of Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts or Spades.

info on how constructor should function.

-If the rank is 11, that means the card is a "jack", which is 1 point.

-If the rank is 12, that means the card is a "queen", which is 2 points.

-If the rank is 13, that means the card is a "king", which is 3 points.

-If the rank is 14, that means the card is a "ace", which is 4 points.

-Any other card is worth 0 (zero) points.

Then some info on how toString() should work.

It should be formatted in a simple style such as these examples.

```
 AH (4) <-Ace of Hearts (worth 4 points)
 KC (3) <-King of Clubs (worth 3 points)
 QD (2) <-Queen of Diamonds (worth 2 points)
 JC (1) <-Jack of Clubs (worth 1 point)
10S (0) <-10 of Spades (worth 0 points)
 9D (0) <-9 of Diamonds (worth 0 points)
```

As you can see, this String should use 2 positions for the rank (if not 10, it will need to start with the space character), followed by the suit character, followed by another space, and finally the number of high-card points it is worth in parentheses.

Below is the current layout of my code which I am having trouble on.

```
  public class Card
    {

    //Holds rank of the card
    private int rank;

    //Holds suit of the card character
    private char suit;

    //Holds the number of high-card points
    private int points;

    /**
     * Constructor to check rank and points
     */
    public Card(int rank, char suit)
    {
        //Initialise instance variables
        this.rank = rank;
        this.suit = suit;

        if (rank > 1 && rank < 15) {
            if (rank == 11)
                points++;
            else if (rank == 12)
                points += 2;
            else if (rank == 13)
                points += 3;
            else if (rank == 14)
                points += 4;
            else
                points += 0;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Gets the rank value
     */
    public int getRank()
    {
        return rank;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the suit
     */
    public char getSuit()
    {
        return suit;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the points
     */
    public int getPoints()
    {
        return points;
    }

    /**
     * String with values of rank,suit,points to be formatted
     */
    public String toString()
    {
        return System.out.printf("%2d %4s %6d", rank, suit, points);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wait, so what's happening right now that isn't supposed to happen? Or do you just want to know how to do the formatting? If the latter, why not use if statements that check if the rank is above a certain value and if it is, you print out the card's name (Jack, Queen, etc.)

Comment: I am getting a format error on toString(), and I also don't get any value when I check getPoints();

Comment: What do you mean you "don't get any value"? And what format error do you get?

Comment: why are you assigning values to points as if it already has one?  the whole thing can be written as `points = Math.max(0, rank - 10);` no `if` needed

Comment: Regard what I said about getPoint(), i'm not sure where to go to format for toString()

Answer (score 3):

You still return a `String`/`StringBuilder` value in your `toString` function. Usually I use a `StringBuilder` with 3 or more concatenations. You had an error because you returned a **print statement**. The **@Override** is OPTIONAL.

*toString() function*

```
@Override public String toString()
{
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    result.append("Suit -> ");
    result.append(suit);
    result.append(", Rank -> ");
    result.append(rank);
    result.append(", Points -> ");
    result.append("(" + points + ")");
    return result.toString();
}
```

*Test program (main.java)*

```
public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Card card1 = new Card(11, 'C');
        System.out.println(card1);
    }

}
```